# Amazon Athena partition with colon(:) is not working

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

When creating partition in Athena, I tried to use the date in the format (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ) then I am not able to query the data

Step 1: Create table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_info (
         id STRING,
         name STRING
) PARTITIONED BY (
        part string
) STORED AS ORC LOCATION 's3://bucket1/data' tblproperties ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

Step 2: Create folder like below and added the files.

```
S3://bucket1/data/part=2019-11-12T14:15:16Z
```

Step 3: Refresh partition
MSCK REPAIR TABLE my_info

Step 4: Query the data
SELECT *
FROM my_info

With this I am **not able to query any data**

If I change the folder to format (yyyy-MM-ddTHH)

**without ’:’** in Step 2

```
s3://bucket1/data/part=2019-11-12T14
```

Then I am able to get the results.

Any idea about why this is not working.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you create the partitioned table the partitioning is implemented as part of the S3 path e.g. for `s3://bucket1/data/part=2019-11-12T14:15:16Z` the `part=2019-11-12T14:15:16Z` section is an S3 path that Athena interprets as a partition when querying the data.

S3 path names have some [restrictions on the characters that can be used](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html):

> The following characters in a key name might require additional code
>   handling and likely need to be URL encoded or referenced as HEX. Some
>   of these are non-printable characters and your browser might not
>   handle them, which also requires special handling:

```
Ampersand ("&")  
Dollar ("$")  
ASCII character ranges 00–1F hex (0–31 decimal) and 7F (127 decimal)  
'At' symbol ("@")  
Equals ("=")  
Semicolon (";")  
Colon (":")  
Plus ("+")  
Space – Significant sequences of spaces may be lost in some uses (especially multiple spaces)  
Comma (",")  
Question mark ("?")
```

In this case it's probably the colons in the path that are not being interpreted by Presto/Athena. To work around this you can use an alternative dividing character in the timestamp e.g. `part=2019-11-12--14-15-16` or omit it altogether.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for your reply. I am able to see the folder in S3 as you have mentioned Athena/Presto might not have implemented these.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can use an URL encoded colon (%3A).

Further, if you which to use `timestamp` as the partition type instead of string, make sure to use a "java.sql.Timestamp compatible [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-)" as [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html) for the CREATE TABLE statement.

So the final url would be `s3://bucket1/data/part=2019-11-12 14%3A15%3A16/`.